# Synthetic homotopy theory lecture question

Tags: logic, homotopy-type-theory, lecture-notes

In this lecture[Logic and topology](https://youtu.be/sOvQEzYGb-c) at 20:21 there is a statement that type isContr which means "is contractible" means that for a given type A and every element x and pointed  element a of type A, there is a path from a to x ( first formula on the slide).
As it of course is definition, it just means everything author may want to, but as ,,"is contractible" has well topological meaning, I would like to ask if it is true?
Because at topological level "is contractible" means that every **closed** path ( loop ) has to be contractible and it is quite different. From other HTT lectures I know that it is a notion of homotopic equivalence to trivial path ( path(A,a,a) = Id) should be used so it looks like path operation is not well defined on this lecture or presenter at least forgot to mention it is a loop in fact...

Or do I do not understand anything?

Comment: Asking us to watch an hour-long video is not acceptable. Please quote accurately the statement that you don't understand in your question.

Comment: There's a time 20:21 in the question and I am asking about technical detail depicted in slide - first formula. Even if You do not want to take a look, you still may explain what Voevodsky used in his construction without reference to the video.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In classical topology, a [contractible space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contractible_space) is one that's equipped with a basepoint and a homotopy from the identity map to the constant map at that basepoint, i.e. a point $a$ and for every point $x$ a path from $x$ to $a$, varying continuously with $x$.  This is exactly what the HoTT definition of IsContr says, except that the "varying continuously" doesn't have to be said explicitly since inside of type theory everything is "continuous".

Comment: That's is what I think of. But notation used in given lecture ( please, take a look at 20:21 of link above) suggests that author uses paths connectivity https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_space#Path_connectedness. So that is why I am asking. In other texts notion of contractible space is used so I presume it is a matter of notation which probably is not very well used in this video and not explained because of lack of the time.

Comment: @kakaz The notation is $(\Sigma a:A)(\Pi x:A)Path(A,a,x)$, i.e. there exists ($\Sigma$) a point $a$ such that for all ($\Pi$) points $x$ there is a (specified) path from $a$ to $x$.

Comment: It differs form notation for example used here: andrew.cmu.edu/user/ulrikb/bielefeld-hits.pdf where "=" is used instead of Path(A,a,x) operator. As "=" I understand any closed path (path in both directions as this depicts reflexivity, or equivalently such path is homotopic to id path)).  It is still not clear for me in that case, because Your answer was in agree wit my previous understanding whilst now I am somehow lost as Path(A,a,x) suggests not contractible but path connected?

Comment: @kakaz The notations Path(A,a,x) and a=x mean the same thing.  Neither of them denote a closed loop; that would be Path(A,x,x) or x=x.  And a closed loop of course need not be constant (i.e. reflexivity).

Comment: The crucial thing to distinguish contractible from path connected is that, as I said in my answer, the path has to "vary continuously" with x.  In a path-connected space there is a point a and a path from every other point x to a, but those paths don't vary continuously with x.  (I just realized there was a typo in my answer, which I will now fix; I hope this wasn't the cause of the confusion.)

Answer (score -2):

I suppose Voevodsky use isContr as "is Contractible" in a meaning that there is at least one element of that type. In fact it would be equivalent to saying that type is not empty. It became clear at the univalence axiom level where there's consequence that "unique existence equals to real excistence". So if some object is unique ( up to isomorphism which is equivalent to up to contractible fibration of type) then there is actually an element of it ( which is the point of we contact to) .